# Best way to use One Note API to GET specific pages in specific section in specific notebook?

Tags: php, onenote-api

According to the [OneNote API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769051.aspx), I can GET specific pages in a specific section using:

```
../sections/{section-id}/pages[?filter,...]
```

... and I can GET a specific section in a specific notebook using:

```
../notebooks/{notebook-id}/sections[filter,...]
```

... but if I try to combine these to GET specific pages in a specific section in a specific notebook, using:

```
../notebooks/{notebook-id}/sections/{section-id}/pages[?filter,...]
```

... I get:

"Badly formed request in oneNoteGet() for: notebooks/< notebook-id >/sections/< section-id >/pages?..."

Of course, I can work around this by first getting a list of all the sections in a specific notebook, then from that list selecting a specific section, and finally requesting specific pages in that section.

But is there a more direct path? Or is this just a deficiency in the current API (in which case I should put in a UserVoice request)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an OData filter on the pages entity set: (make sure you expand it)

```
GET ~/pages?$filter=parentNotebook/id%20eq%20'YOURNOTEBOOKID'&$expand=parentNotebook
```

Comment: Thanks for super-prompt response, Jorge. Will try this later today and let you know how I go.

Comment: Yes, that works very nicely, thanks, Jorge - so much cleaner than my clunky workaround.
(Just a bit puzzled about the '$' in front of 'filter' and 'expand' - in my PHP code, these become variables.)

Comment: Just as a follow-up to my bracketed comment above about the preprended '$' causing problems in PHP code: the official OData documentation specifies the prepended sigil before query parameters but the OneNote API documentation omits it - which makes it easier for PHP programmers :) (I could escape the '$' ('\$'), but that seems like overkill when simply omitting it works fine.)

Comment: Yep, good question: We are an OData API - therefore we support $filters in our entities. We also happen to support the same without "$", but strict OData suggests to add that. http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Jorge, this also means by changing the filter to:

```
GET ~/pages?$filter=parentNotebook/name%20eq%20'YOURNOTEBOOKNAME'&$expand=parentNotebook
```

one can get all the pages in a notebook based on just the notebook name (which is something I've been looking for).